# ObjectiveFlickr & Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, objectiveflickr

I'm attempting to integrate [ObjectiveFlickr](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr) into my project - everything seems to run fine, however as soon as I execute the following:

```
[request callAPIMethodWithGET:@"flickr.photos.getRecent" arguments:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"per_page", nil]]
```

I get an exc bad access error.  I've been trying to figure this out for a while and any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the mistake of declaring the variables locally - set the request and context variables as properties (i.e. instance vars) and it gets rid of the exc bad access error.