# Error when calling callAPIMethodWithGET in ObjectiveFlickr

Tags: objectiveflickr

I am trying to use [ObjectiveFlickr](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr/blob/master/README.markdown) with the following sample API call but my code ends with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I made sure that my key and shared secret exist in flickr:

```
OFFlickrAPIContext *context = [[OFFlickrAPIContext alloc] initWithAPIKey:apiKey sharedSecret:sharedSecret];    
OFFlickrAPIRequest *request = [[OFFlickrAPIRequest alloc] initWithAPIContext:context];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request callAPIMethodWithGET:@"flickr.photos.getRecent" arguments:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"per_page", nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, look here: [ObjectiveFlickr & Xcode 4.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289125/objectiveflickr-xcode-4-5-2/14958642#14958642)

Declare the context and request variables as properties instead, and it'll get rid of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS